# Are $\forall x\forall y(p(x,y)\leftrightarrow p(y,x))$ and $\forall x\forall y p(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y\forall x p(x,y)$ tautologies?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

$$\forall x\forall y( p(x,y) \leftrightarrow p(y,x) )$$

I don't know if this formula is a tautology or not.

I think the order inside the predicates is not important and therefore, it's a tautology.

Thanks for your help!

What about this one ?

$$\forall x\forall y p(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y\forall x p(x,y).$$

The order in the all-quantifier isn't important too, so i think this one is a tautology too, right ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/6267#6267) is a MathJax tutorial.  Consider if $p(x,y)$ is $x<y$

Comment: If $ p(x,y) $ is symetric.

Comment: The second statement is not the same as the first.

Comment: Ah right ! So the first formula isn't a tautology. THanks

Comment: What about the second one ? @JCAA yeah i just wanna check both of them, if they are Tautologies

Comment: You should give a definition of tautology.

Comment: The second one is a tautology simply because you can switch the order of two universal quantifiers, What cannot be done is switch the order of a universal quantifier and an existential one

Comment: The second one is not a tautology as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Tautologies_versus_validities_in_first-order_logic. But it is a *logical validity* (true in any structure). So it really depends on what you mean by tautology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$\forall x\forall y( p(x,y) \leftrightarrow p(y,x) )$$

Consider the interpretation $\mathcal{I}(P) = \{\langle x, y \rangle: x \text{ loves }y\}$. Sadly enough, just because you love someone doesn't always mean they loves you back: We can easily think of a structure where John loves Peter (i.e. $\langle John, Peter \rangle \in \mathcal{I}(P)$) but Peter doesn't love John ($\langle Peter, John \rangle \not \in \mathcal{I}(P)$). Thus $P(x,y)$ does not imply $P(y,x)$. Since we found is at least one interpretation that makes the formula false, it is **not tautological**.

The interpretation of a predicate is a set of tuples. **Tuples are ordered**: $\langle a, b \rangle \neq \langle b, a\rangle$. Since the order of the objects in the interpretation of the predicate matters, so does the order in which we write the terms down in the expression.

---

> $$\forall x\forall y p(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y\forall x p(x,y).$$

> The order in the all-quantifier isn't important

A bit sloppy, but yes: In general, $\forall x \forall y \phi$ is logically equvivalent to $\forall y \forall x \phi$; that is, **we can commute quantifiers of the same type**. So yes, this formula indeed **is tautological**.

Comment: clear answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the domain $\{0,1\}$ with $p=\{(0,1)\}$.

For the second, it is *valid*, if that's what you mean; see this:

[image]

This image was produced using [this tool](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80y(p(x,y)))%E2%86%94(%E2%88%80y%E2%88%80x%20p(y,x))).